# Octal character representation in keyboard macros

Tags: functions, keyboard-macros

I generated a macro as a help for generating indices for words I have marked before. Now this macro looks as follows

```
(fset 'index
   "\367\\index{\C-y")
```

What does `\367`stand for and where can I look it up?

Comment: How did you get this representation for the macro? Did you type a M-w in your macro?  I suspect my answer misses something, after reading section 2.3.3.4 of the elisp manual.

Comment: @JeanPierre : I used M-x insert-kbd-macro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a representation of the character whose code is 367 in octal.  This "general escape representation" is described in the [elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/General-Escape-Syntax.html#General-Escape-Syntax).

You can use the function `text-char-description` as:

```
M-: (text-char-description ?\367)
```

or `M-x describe-char` with point on the char

to see this is the character DIVISION SIGN.

Now the question is what does it stand for?

The short answer is that this character is the representation of *the keyboard event* `M-w` in a string. For the details I recommend reading section [Putting Keyboard Events in Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Strings-of-Events.html#Strings-of-Events) of the elisp manual.

Also note that the manual discourages storing keyboard events in strings and recommends using vectors instead.

Comment: Do you maybe know why the division sign appears there at all? Which function does it have? I tried to look it up but didn't find a useful source.

Comment: I suspect this is in fact a representation of M-w, that's why I asked you about this.  Unfortunately, `insert-kbd-macro`  does not bring up a string for me.  I'm currently investigating.

Comment: Oh yes, now I understand. I indeed typed M-w to have the marked word saved before I paste it. Now it's clear, thank you very much!

Comment: "`insert-kbd-macro` does not bring up a string for me" - it depends which keys you have in the macro: if all of them are plain characters that fit in range 0-255, then Emacs will use a string, otherwise a vector.

Comment: @npostavs Yes indeed, thanks!